# How to do a describe in livesql.oracle.com

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, describe

In livesql.oracle.com I can't use any SQL*Plus commands. Is there another way to do a describe of a table than by clicking on your schema?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question. I suggest you split your statement into just the question part (and make it a question rather than a statement) and remove your solution from the "question" and put it in its own answer.

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a blog or a forum; its a Q&A site and the Q part should just be a question and the A part should just be the answer and you shouldn't mix the two up. You don't need to close the question. Instead, [edit] the question and remove the answer from the question and re-post that answer part as a separate answer in the text box below and change the rest of the text from an "I've done this ...." statement to a "How do I do this ....?" question. It doesn't matter if you post a question and immediately post an answer to it; in fact, that is a good thing.

Answer (score 1):

Like others, I was looking for a way to do a describe of a table in livesql.oracle.com. For those who are still looking for a good alternative, I've solved it using a table function like this.

Maybe someone else will be helped with this.

```
create  type desc_type as object(
"Name" varchar2(35), "Null?" varchar2(10), "Type" varchar2(100));

create type desc_type_tbl is table of desc_type;

create or replace function mydesc(p_table_name varchar2) return desc_type_tbl as
  l_tab desc_type_tbl := desc_type_tbl();
  cursor cur is select column_name name,
case nullable when 'N' then 'NOT NULL' else null end as nul
, data_type || case when data_precision is not null and data_scale > 0 then '('||data_precision||','||data_scale||')'
                   when data_precision is not null then '('||data_precision||')'
                   when data_type in ('VARCHAR2','CHAR')  then '('||data_length||')'
                   else '' end as typ
from user_tab_columns
where table_name=p_table_name
order by column_id;

begin
  for r_desc in cur loop
    l_tab.extend();
    l_tab(l_tab.last) := desc_type(r_desc.name, r_desc.nul, r_desc.typ);
  end loop;
  return l_tab;
end;
/

select * from mydesc('CARS');

Name        Null?       Type        
----------- ----------- ------------
LPLATE      NOT NULL    VARCHAR2(8) 
CHASSISNO               NUMBER(7)   
BRAND                   VARCHAR2(12)
PRICE                   NUMBER(7,2)
```